# Order of evaluation for short-circuit operators and let in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, operator-precedence

In OCaml, when using a `let` to assign an alias to a short-circuit operator (`&&` or `||`), it no longer short-circuits evaluation of the operands.

This is not intuitive. What is the reason for this behavior?

Consider the following code:

```
let f() = Printf.printf "f"; false;;
let g() = Printf.printf "g"; true;;
let a = (&&);;

f() && g();; (* outputs 'f' *)

(&&) (f()) (g());; (* outputs 'f' *)

a (f()) (g());; (* outputs 'gf' *)
```

This also happens with `let ... in`, so `let b = (&&) in b (f()) (g());;` also outputs `gf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `&&` is a primitive operator whose semantics is quite different from a normal function. In fact, `(&&)` is more or less equivalent to `fun x y -> x && y`, which as explained by nlucaroni will evaluate its arguments before they are being applied (in an unspecified order, which happens to be usually right-to-left, but you should not rely on it).

You can see that by using `ocaml -dlambda`. This will launch an interpreter which outputs the translation in one of the intermediate languages of each command you enter. Then, you'll have the following result:

```
# (&&);;
(function prim/1044 prim/1043 (&& prim/1044 prim/1043))
- : bool -> bool -> bool = <fun>
```

The `lambda` format is not documented, but it should be clear enough that eta-expansion is happening.

Comment: I never tried -dlambda through the ocaml toplevel, nice.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluation is not lazy, so `f` and `g` will be evaluated *before* they are applied as arguments to your function.

Comment: But the manual (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec138) says that operators `&&` and `||` are special (short-circuit), and they behave like so in the first examples. The manual also states: *Note: the operators &&, ||, and ~- are handled specially and it is not advisable to change their meaning.* But it doesn't seem clear why the `let` interferes with this.

Comment: Because the `let` isn't special. `external a : bool -> bool -> bool = "%sequand"` will work though.

Comment: @nlucaroni this does not work for me with OCaml 4.01, and in fact I'd say that it's not really possible to define a function that exhibit this behavior (short of using `bool Lazy,t` arguments of course). `&&` is a primitive operator that is handled specially by the runtime.

Comment: I'm using 4.01.0 and verified the behavior. Maybe you copied the function incorrectly. Yes, lazy would be required generally.

Comment: @nlucaroni, Virgile's answer seemed clearer to me so I chose it, but your "%sequand" did work for me (OCaml 4.00.0). I hope I won't ever need to use such dark spells however.

Comment: @nlucaroni yes, you're right, I probably messed up somewhere the first time I checked that.